# General design - Where do I put centrally accessed objects

Tags: ios

I have my main app delegate
I have a few UIViewController derived instances driven by a Storyboard

Say I'd like to provide a centralized persistence layer for my application - perhaps Core Data of SQLite. Where would I put those objects? I'm missing some centrally accessible "Application" class you can access from all the UIViewController instances.

Is there a pattern to follow here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is your model layer. There are two main ways to manage the model:

- At application startup, create the main model object and hand it to the first view controller.
- Make the main model object a Singleton.

The "main model object" in both cases is generally some kind of object manager. It could be a document, or it could be a `PersonManager` if you have a bunch of `Person` objects. This object will vend model objects from your persistence store (generally Core Data).

The advantage of a Singleton here is that it's a little easier to implement and you don't have to pass around the manager. The advantage of a non-Singleton is that it's easier to have more than one (for a document-based system), and it's easier to test and reason about non-singletons than singletons. That said, probably 80% of my projects use a singleton model manager.

As a side note, that you appear to already understand: never store the model in the application delegate, and never use the application delegate as a "rendezvous point" to get to the model. That is, never have a `sharedModel` method on the application delegate. If you find yourself calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` anywhere in your code, you're almost always doing something wrong. Hanging data on the application delegate makes code reuse extremely difficult.

Answer (score 2):

you should check the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern):

> In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a design pattern
>   that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object. This is
>   useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across
>   the system. The concept is sometimes generalized to systems that
>   operate more efficiently when only one object exists, or that restrict
>   the instantiation to a certain number of objects. The term comes from
>   the mathematical concept of a singleton.

here is a source for a example implementation: [What should my Objective-C singleton look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like)

and here is the direct link for the modern solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/145395/644629

Comment: Exactly what I would have wrote.  More modern implementations use GCD's dispatch_once function though.

Comment: FYI, the linked question is fairly out of date. There best answer (`dispatch_once`) is buried way down in the list. http://iosptl.com/posts/the-singleton-pattern/

Comment: yes thats true, but i think he need a Singleton Model Class to store some global data.

Comment: Absolutely agreed (well, about 80% of the time... :D See my answer for the other common solution).

Comment: That's the one I was referring to as buried way down on the list. I'd suggest down-voting the out-of-date answers, but that would just be mean. :) They were completely appropriate when they were written.

Comment: yes, i wrote first the comment and then read the your full comment, thats why i delete my last comment. =)

Comment: offtopic: should i implement a dealloc method for a singleton. maybe its cleaner to implement the method, but it isn't necessary, or?

Answer (score 0):

Go with a singleton pattern, which has scope of application lifetime.

```
@interface DataManager ()

@end

#pragma mark -

@implementation DataManager

#pragma mark - Shared Instance

static DataManager* sharedInstance = nil;

#pragma mark - Singleton Methods

- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];

  if (self) {
    // Initialization code here.
  }

  return self;
}

+ (DataManager*)sharedInstance
{
    @synchronized([DataManager class])
    {
        if (!sharedInstance) {

      //[[self alloc] init];
      sharedInstance = [[DataManager alloc] init];

    }
        return sharedInstance;
    }

    return nil;
}

+ (id)alloc
{
    @synchronized([DataManager class])
    {
        NSAssert(sharedInstance == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance \
             of a singleton.");

    sharedInstance = [super alloc];

    return sharedInstance;
    }

    return nil;
}


@end
```

Declare your properties in .h file and synthesize them here in .m file.

To use that property just call:

```
// set value
[[DataManager sharedInstance] setSharedProperty:@"ABC"]; // If its a string

// get Value
NSLog(@"value :  %@", [[DataManager sharedInstance] sharedProperty]);
```

Hope this is what you required.

Enjoy Coding :)